# What is this character? 始める_!

Tags: katakana, hiragana

Probably a silly question.  I assume that it is just a stylistic way of writing some katakana or hiragana that I know.  The image is from ヘタリア but I’ve seen it in a few places.  The full sentence is basically “let the global conference begin.”[image]

> 始める_!

Comment: An appropriate place for this type of question: https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Is this character a そ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53835/is-this-character-a-%e3%81%9d)

I don't like answering in comments, so I'll post it here.

The character is a two-stroke そ with a dakuten: ぞ.

Related:

- [In what situations can you use ぞ as a sentence ender](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/617/in-what-situations-can-you-use-%e3%81%9e-as-a-sentence-ender)